# DNS: Why do "naked" URLs resolve differently than www URLs?

Tags: url, dns, ip-address

I have a domain: www.example.com. When a user types "www.example.com" in their web browser, DNS resolves to the correct webpage, but when the user types just "example.com" (without the "www"), DNS can't resolve to the correct IP address. What are the differences between the DNS resolution process for www.example.com and example.com?

Comment: A good example of this is http://www.x.org vs http://x.org, or, indeed, any website from the 90s.

Comment: something to do with the existence of an HTTP listener on the port that `www` refers to, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

The resolution process is the same, it's the names that are different. That is, `www.example.com` is not the same name as `example.com`, in exactly the same way that `Jane Doe` is not the same name as `Doe`. It is possible, even common, to set things up so that the two different names `www.example.com` and `example.com` resolve to the same IP addresses, but there is nothing that makes that happen by itself. It's an active choice to make it like that.